# Display: flex não funciona

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, sou um tanto quanto iniciante, já usei um pouco HTML e CSS, mas não tenho muita experiência, devido isso estou com uma certa dificuldade, ao utilizar o display: flex no arquivo CSS não aparece o resultado esperado, já tentei de diversas formas e nenhuma funcionou, gostaria de saber qual seria o erro, e se possível, como corrigir o problema em questão.

Segue HTML e CSS:

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 120px 1fr 60px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "cabecalho" "principal" "rodape";
}

.cabecalho {
    grid-area: cabecalho;
    background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 25px 20px rgb(0, 195, 255);
}

.cabecalho > h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
}

.cabecalho > h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.principal {
    grid-area: principal;
    height: calc(100vh - 180px);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
    border-radius: 50px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0, 129, 168);
}

.conteudo{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(0, 63, 122);
}

.modulos {
    display: flex;
}

.rodape{
    grid-area: rodape;
    background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px -12px 25px 20px rgb(0, 195, 255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
    position: sticky;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: rgb(0, 63, 122);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\estilo.css">
    <title>Curso PHP - Cod3r</title>

</head>

<body>

    <header class="cabecalho">

        <h1><strong> Curso PHP - Cod3r </strong></h1>
        <h2>Índice dos Exercícios</h2>

    </header>

    <main class="principal">

        <div class="conteudo">

            <nav class="modulos">

                <div class="modulo">

                    <h3>Módulo 01</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Módulo 02</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Módulo 03</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Módulo 04</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Módulo 05</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Módulo 06</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </nav>

        </div>

    </main>

    <footer class="rodape">

        <strong>M52</strong>COD3R © 2021

    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Segue imagem do resultado:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB8Cy.png

A ideia é que os módulos fiquem lado a lado, e não "empilhados" como estão agora, mas não estou conseguindo achar o erro.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: José, quando vc apresenta um problema tentando entender o que causa o comportamento inesperado por você e apenas coloca código na tela não vai te ajudar a encontrar ajuda. Pois parece que vc quer que as pessoas pensem por você e isso não é legal. Tente adicionar imagens de como está sendo exibido o resultado para você e como você gostaria que fosse exibido.

Comment: Farei isso hoje, não está mais igual o que foi colocado aqui, na tentativa de fazer funcionar acabei alterando, mas vou atualizar ele aqui ou voltar ao que está na postagem pra ter as imagens do resultado, mas apenas pra fazer uma breve explicação, são 6 módulos, que aparecem "empilhados", a ideia é que fossem 2 linhas, cada uma com 3 módulos, o display: flex deveria deixar os módulos lado a lado, após eu iria organizar a exibição, mas não funciona da forma como coloquei, se eu colocar em outras tags funciona, mas na que preciso não funciona. Obrigado pelo comentário, mais tarde irei atualizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que tal tentar assim, deixe cada modulo dentro de uma div, no seu caso seria a modulo, para que cada modulo ocupasse uma determinada área, assim como abaixo:

```
 <nav class="modulos">

   <div class="modulo">

      <h3>Módulo 01</h3>

         <ul>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
          </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="modulo">

      <h3>Módulo 02</h3>

        <ul>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Exercício A</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
//assim até o módulo 6

  </div>

</nav>
```

Depois disso, vá ao seu CSS e em modulos e acrescente a direção row, provavelmente deve funcionar agora.

```
.modulos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Acredite que assim funcione, meu conselho pra uma próxima vez se acontecer é, tentar olhar visualmente as suas divs nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor do navegador. Acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: Funcionou realmente, quando foi separado em duas divs lá dentro funcionou, deu pra entender o que estava acontecendo agora, muito obrigado.